# Passing variables inside a variable to nested script

Tags: bash

Let's say I have script `alpha.sh`. The overly simplified version of it is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

ENV_PARAMS_FOR_BRAVO="FOO=bar"

result=$($ENV_PARAMS_FOR_BRAVO bash bravo.sh)
echo $results
```

And then a script `bravo.sh`, whose overly simplified version is:

```
echo "foo is $FOO"
```

When I run the above `alpha` script, I get an error, because it tries to execute `$ENV_PARAMS_FOR_BRAVO` as if it was the command itself. When I run the same exact command replacing the above variable with its contents (`result=$(FOO=bar bash bravo.sh)`), the script works as expected.

In the actual version of the script, I need to pass a lot more variables to `bravo` from `alpha`, so the `$ENV_PARAMS_FOR_BRAVO` variable is meant to serve as an aggregation for a curated list of arguments for `bravo`. I also can't pass them to `bravo` as arguments because many of these are optional and will shift the real arguments `bravo` takes that are NOT optional.

What's the issue with the above approach and how do I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `export` the variable `FOO` so it is visible for all calling scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

export FOO="bar"

result=$(./bravo.sh)
echo $result

> foo is bar
```

**Alternate solution if you only want it to `bravo.sh` and not to all following scripts:**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
result=$(export FOO="bar"; ./bravo.sh)
echo $result

result2=$(./bravo.sh)
echo $result2
```

Output will be

```
> foo is bar
> foo is
```